# Trying to hide object during animation

Tags: animation

I'm trying to make a animation where, from a clean slate, more and more objects are to appear one after another. I have seen a method where you make the material transparent, but this doesn't seem like a good way to do it...
Since I have about 100 object that I want to animate, that all have the same material, I don't want to make a duplicate of the material for every object.

Do you have a better solution for this problem?

Best regards
/John

Comment: When ever I have had to do this I simple animate the location from on-off screen over 1 frame.

Comment: Only use rob's method, if you aren't using motion blur.

Comment: an easy way could have been to create an animation between a Diffuse and a Transparent shader, then in the NLA move the Strip of each object to change the moment they appear, but it looks like, unlike a move Strip, you can't change a Shader Strip position of an object without changing it for all the objects sharing the same Strip, am I right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't need your objects to appear gradually:

1. Select your object, go into the *Outliner*, deactivate the *Show In Renders* option (camera icon) and create a keyframe (<kbd>i</kbd>).
2. Now in the *Timeline* move to the frame where you want your object to appear, go into the *Outliner*, reactivate the camera icon and create a new keyframe.
3. If you duplicate your object, you just have to move the 2nd keyframe in the *Dopesheet* to change the time of its appearance.

You can also keyframe the *Show In Viewports* option (monitor icon) so that you can see in the viewport what will happen in your render.

These 2 options, *Show In Renders* and *Show In Viewports* are also available and keyframable in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Visibility*.

Comment: I followed the instructions but failed because, the pointer must be over the visibility, "eye" icon when you create the keyframe, otherwise it will assume you are animating translation of the object and you will not be given the choise for visibility.
At least, so it is in Blender 2.8x

Comment: hello, not sure to understand, in my 2.8 version you can't keyframe the viewport visibility (eye icon). There was another way to animate the visibility through the Shade Editor, that would have been more relevant to the question but I can't put my hand on it...

Comment: @mooboots You are right I was trying out the Render "camera" icon, that works.
The visibility in viewport can indeed be accessed from the Properties panel > Object > Visibility.
It effects the "monitor" not "eye" visibility. Be sure to set the value from the tickboxes in the Properties or Timeline and not from the Outliner, because it won’t “stick”.

Comment: oh ok I see that viewport visibility only works in the Properties panel, not optimal though, weird, anyway I guess it's rarely useful...

Comment: It works, I'm fine. After I had ticked selection inside the object properties, I tried to change the keyframe status from the Outliner, THAT doesn't work.  You need to do all from the Properties.  My bad

Comment: yes it's not logical that it can't be keyframed in the Outliner, plus when you keyframe, it makes the keyframes disappear in the Dope Sheet, which might not be convenient   :/

Answer (score 4):

For those who do not understand the discussion above: I found the answer [here](https://www.versluis.com/2015/04/how-to-create-keyframe-animations-in-blender/). The trick is to **hover** your cursor over the properties you’d like to save in this keyframe. This means you open the properties and literally hover your mouse over the properties "Show in ... Viewports" and "Show in ... Render"

[image]

Comment: Hello, since a few versions you don't even need the shortcut, you can just click the dots on the right of field, which then become rotated squares afterwards